# Python script run through supervisord output buffering

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a script which make a request to api get data and create pandas dataframe and if certain condition is fulfilled it send another request to api and prints result.

Simple version would like this:

```
request= api_reguest(data)
table = json_normalize()
table = table[table['field']>1]
if table.empty:
     pass
else:
     var1,var2,var3 = table[['var1','var2','var3']]
     another_request = api_request2(var1,var2,var3)
     print var1,var2,var3

threading.Timer(1, main).start()
```

It all works fine, but when I run it as a process in supervisord it stops logging and sending requests to api after about 12 hours. It is clearly the problem of output buffering, because if I restart the process it starts working again.

I already tried all possible solutions for output buffering in python:

sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
sys.stdout.flush()
Running script with -u option
Running script through stdbuf

My feeling is that it is something to do with supervisord buffer rather then with the script itself, but I can't figure out how to turn off supervisord buffer.

Can you advise me please?